# How do I unlock things to manufacture?

Tags: perpetuum

How do I unlock things to manufacture in the Factory in Perpetuum?
In the game, there are three ways of getting items scanned into blueprints. But I'm confused with that.

Do you have to either:

1. Research it
2. Reverse-engineer it
3. "Invent" it?
4. Find [something] as an artifact and then decode it?
5. Decode something?
6. All of the above?

or how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to manufacture an item in the **factory**, you'll need a **Calibration Template** for that particular item.

A **Calibration Template** can be created through **Reverse Engineering**, where you'll need a prototype of that item (or simply one production batch for ammunition/charges) alongside a **Decoder** and a small NIC fee.

A **Prototype** is a stronger, efficient and more powerful version of a particular component (ie. Robot/Shield/Weapon/etc., with the exception of ammo), usually about 20 times more expensive (and longer to make) than its standard manufactured counterparts.
You can create a **Prototype** in the **Prototype Factory**, provided you have researched it with **Kernels**, and have the appropriate commodities and NIC to manufacture it.